# Why a service of main module available in other modules?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have a main module `main` which contains a service `mainService`. I have then injected another module `moduleA` in my main module. I randomly called `mainService` in `moduleA` without injecting `main` module and was amazed to see it is working fine.

```
angular.module('main', ['moduleA']);
angular.module('main').service('mainService', function(){
   //insert code here
});

angular.module('moduleA', []);
angular.module('moduleA').controller('abc', function(mainService){
   //mainService available here, without injecting main module
});
```

I want to know the reason behind this. I once read in a comment that a service defined in a module is available everywhere in the application, but couldn't find the source. Is it ok to continue using it like this?

I'm using `AngularJS ver 1.3.15` if it helps.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes you can use the service of main because of parent child relationship. "main" is a parent module and "moduleA" its child/dependency module.

Any serivce, controller, directive defined in "main" module will be available with "moduleA"

Lets understand this concept with a more complex scenario

```
angular.module('main', ['moduleA', 'moduleB']);


angular.module('moduleA', []);
angular.module('moduleA').service('moduleAService', function(){
   //insert code here
});

angular.module('moduleB', []);
angular.module('moduleB').controller('abc', function(moduleAService){
   //moduleAService available here, without injecting moduleA module
});
```

Now in this case moduleA and moduleB are totally independent but still moduleB can access moduleA services

It is because main module is dependent on moduleA and moduleB. So moduleA services is injected in main module and moduleB being a child of "main" module can access it.

Comment: Adding further details.

Comment: Initially I also thought so. But the thing is, sibling services are also available everywhere. For example, a service `serviceA` defined in `moduleA` is also available in `moduleB` without DI. I was wondering if the parent-child/sibling-sibling relationship is the only reason behind this or is there something more to it?

Comment: Actually it is not the sibling relation. Let us assume a case when there are 2 children who do not like to share a thing.  However, with parent child relationship, property of 1 child is transferred to the parent and now the other child can access it requesting parent. Just like in our case - though there is no dependency injection, still you can access the service because of parent which is having the control of the services.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting it now. Thanks

Comment: @sahilgupta - Welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

Injecting something like a service in the parent, makes it available to all its children.

Answer (score -2):

Worth reading http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2015/05/21/angular-dependencies-naming-clash/ to know few more things about modules.

Summary from the post:

> It turns out AngularJS doesn’t really care where it takes things to inject from as long as the name matches
>
> In AngularJS there is no such thing as module you depend on. Even when you ask for a thing, you cannot be sure you’ll get the one you expect just because you declare dependency on module that has exactly this thing. This is all one giant toolbox.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Please add main parts of the external link here as an answer. If in the future that link is broken this answer will be useless. Thank you

Comment: added few summary content from the linked post as suggested in the comment.