# how to call a ui-router state declared in another angular module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have created two angularjs module of the same application. How can I call from the module A the state x declared in the module B? Do you have any idea or workaround?

when I call the state `x` in this way

```
$state.go('x')
```

from the module A, it isn't found

Comment: Create a parent state which has dependency on module A and module B. And use the states across.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Yes coming in a minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// This is your parent module

var app = angular.module('app', [
        'ui.router',
        // Application modules
        'moduleA',
        'moduleB'
    ]);

// This is your child module 1    
var moduleA = angular.module('moduleA', ['ui.router']);

moduleA.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {


            $stateProvider
                .state('moduleA', {
                    url: '/route1',
                    controller: 'moduleAController',
                    template: "<div>Test</div>"
                });
            }]);



// This is your child module 2     
var moduleB = angular.module('moduleB', ['ui.router']);

moduleB.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {


            $stateProvider
                .state('moduleB', {
                    url: '/route2',
                    controller: 'moduleBController',
                    template: "<div>Test</div>"
                });
            }]);
```

Explanation - With this you have one parent module with 2 child modules. Child modules services, controllers and directives can be used across these 3 modules without any dependency injection.

Comment: but where is the parent state?

Comment: Oops! That was a typo - I meant parent module.

Comment: then inside the controller `mobuleBController` I can go to the state `moduleA` by executing `state.go('moduleA')`

Comment: Yes. That you can do without a doubt.

Comment: For details you can also refer to my answer at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729386/why-a-service-of-main-module-available-in-other-modules/30729467?noredirect=1#comment49515467_30729467